# ZF2: unable to fetch or create an instance for partial

Tags: zend-framework2, partial-views, renderpartial, partials

I am trying to use partials in my layout on ZF2.

I tried few methods (including those that are described here, where a user has to include a partial to the rout in the module config). Every time I am getting the same error.

For example, I am following instructions from the ZF2 documentation: http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/modules/zend.view.helpers.partial.html#zend-view-helpers-initial-partial

partials.phtml is in the same folder as the layout.phtml. The server (and I tried both, apache and building PHP server) throws an error:

```
[Fri Jun 14 18:40:34 2013] 127.0.0.1:36616 [500]: / - Uncaught exception 'Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException' with message 
'Zend\View\HelperPluginManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance for partial' in /var/www/frameworks/ZF2/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php:496
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/frameworks/ZF2/library/Zend/ServiceManager/AbstractPluginManager.php(103): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->get('partial', true)
#1 /var/www/frameworks/ZF2/library/Zend/View/Renderer/PhpRenderer.php(378): Zend\ServiceManager\AbstractPluginManager->get('partial', NULL)
#2 /var/www/frameworks/ZF2/library/Zend/View/Renderer/PhpRenderer.php(397): Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer->plugin('partial')
#3 /var/www/html/zf2.tutorial/module/Application/view/layout/layout.phtml(129): Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer->__call('partial', Array)
#4 /var/www/html/zf2.tutorial/module/Application/view/layout/layout.phtml(129): Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer->partial('partial.phtml', Array)
#5 /var/www/frameworks/ZF2/library/Zend/View/Renderer/PhpRenderer. in /var/www/frameworks/ZF2/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php on line 496
```

I am using PHP5.5.0RC3, ZF2.2.1 and Apache 2.2.15

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: need to paste more code..

Comment: Okay, Andrew, I will include more code later today when I get home.